# Redirect domains and subdomains with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, lamp

Right now *.foo.com and *.bar.com are aliased to the same vhost with LAMP. Right now it, of course, shows the same content with every URL. But I don't actually want this to be what happens, and I want the other domains to actually redirect to foo.com. I'm assuming this is possible with the .htaccess file.

EDIT: I'm hosting this on my own server, so I'd also like the IP address to redirect to foo.com

Answer (score 1):

Use a rewrite condition in your .htaccess to selected everything not for foo.com and redirect it then:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foo\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://foo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I've added this exactly how you've given it, but it also seems to redirect the domain I wanted to redirect everything to, resulting in an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: There was a typo in the condition. Now I tested it, and it seems to work :)